# Проблема с кодом Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

я через левую кнопку мыши в коде даю обьекту силу(Rigidbody), и так же действует проверка на земле игрок - или нет. Но сила не применяется при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши
Начал изучать геймдев в этом году зимой, не совсем все знаю, поэтому если это легко решить, можно просто ответ сказать что делать?
Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isGrounded;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(isGrounded == true)
        {
            if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                rb.AddForce(0f, 100f, 0f);
                isGrounded = false;
                rb.isKinematic = false;
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            rb.isKinematic = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ты сначала пытаешься применить силу к телу, на которое не воздействует физика, а потом включаешь это воздействие физики, естественно оно не будет работать. В условии, где проверяешь нажатие кнопки, перемести isKinematic выше, чем AddForce.

Comment: Попробую сейчас

Comment: Спасибо, не знал